# Как программно получить S.M.A.R.T информацию от SSD. OS - Debian

Tags: ssd, smart

Собственно сабж. Есть программа работающая в Debian, она должна уметь получить информацию от SSD и довести ее до пользователя. Вопрос заключается в том, что хотелось бы понять каким образом можно получить эту инфу программно. Парсинг вывода smartctl и иже с ними не подходит, нужно получать и интерпретировать информацию самостоятельно.

Comment: Посмотрите нужное в исходных кодах smartctl?)

Comment: https://www.smartmontools.org/browser/trunk/smartmontools собственно исходники